# Online shopping steps: payment and confirmation vs review and payment

Tags: checkout

You are shopping online and you have already added some products to your shopping bag and proceeding to checkout. 
From the below options which one works better?

[image: Two options: payment then confirmation / review order then payment]

Answer (score 2):

> From the below options which one works better?

For both, the online-shop operators and the customers, a combination of both options works best:

1. Shopping bag
2. Delivery address
3. Review order: without, the customer has to cancel an acciental order which is avoidable bad UX. Also as a customer I would not buy anything without knowing what is on my list.
4. Payment
5. Confirmation: tell the customer that everything went well and the order will be sent in the next x days. Don't leave the user in the dark; the confirmation is like the "Good bye and have a nice day" of physical stores.

Also, keep in mind, that most things in online shopping are regulated by laws. In some countries the online-shop has to show a detailed listing before the final checkout.

Comment: Good suggestion Marvin.

Comment: Reason why i didn't include confirmation in steps is because i feel confirmation is not a step. Yes, showing a confirmation page is necessary (agreed) but i am a bit doubtful in showing it as a step because when you are making a payment online, the actions you have to take is "Provide address" > choose payment method > review orders > pay. Showing confirmation as a step increases the no. of steps visually.  What do you think?

Comment: I agree with you. I saw your "steps" as a more abstract workflow than a concrete visualisation for the user. In this case I probably also would not show confirmation as a step.